# Docker-Compose - Push application from Bitbucket to ECR

Tags: docker, docker-compose, bitbucket-pipelines, amazon-ecr

I need to push a docker application from bitbucket into ECR. The docker-compose file spins up 3 containers (PHP, PHP-FPM and NGINX) that I need to push to ECR. I understand I need to tag the containers with the repo name before I push them but where do I do this? What would the bitbucket-pipeline look like?

```
version: "3.1"

services:

  php:
    image: xxx/docker/php:7.3-dev
    container_name: xxx-php
    working_dir: /application
    volumes:
      - ./:/application
      - "~/.composer:/home/root/.composer"
    environment:
      MEM_LIMIT: "512m"
    networks:
      - app-network
    depends_on:
      - database

  phpfpm:
    image: xxx/docker/php:7.3-fpm-dev
    container_name: xxx-phpfpm
    environment:
      MAX_REQUESTS: 100
      MAX_CHILDREN: 10
      SLOW_TIMEOUT: 10
      TERM_TIMEEOUT: 10
      MEM_LIMIT: 256m
    volumes:
      - ./:/application
    networks:
      - app-network
    depends_on:
      - database

  nginx:
    image: xxx/docker/nginx:1.10.0-
    container_name: xxx-nginx
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    environment:
      UPSTREAM_MODE: compose
    volumes:
      - ./:/application
    networks:
      - app-network
      - reactor_app-network
    depends_on:
      - phpfpm
```

Answer (score 0):

So the pipeline should look like the below

First do a container scanning for any vulnerabilities using [clair](https://github.com/quay/clair) which is the mostly used container scanning tool. You can look for other open source options if you like.

Then the second stage should be picking up the Dockerfiles from your repo and build the images. The image build for can be done by launching container with docker-dind image

```
docker build -t test:$env .
```

Post which you should login to ECR by using [get-login](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/get-login.html)

```
aws ecr get-login --registry-ids 012345678910 023456789012
```

Using the output of above command you should be able to login to ECR.

Then perform a [docker push](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/push/)